# How to use javascript OR operator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

I've been breaking my head over this 'simple' javascript snippet:

```
$("#hitbox").mouseleave(function() {
  if($("#sub-wrapper-1").height() < 179 || $("#sub-wrapper-2").height() < 179 ) {     
    $("#hitbox").animate({ "height" : '0px' }, 800), 
  } else {
    $("#hitbox").stop();
  }
});
```

Could you guys nudge me in the right direction on how to use the `OR` operator in javascript? The above code doesn't throw any errors, but it seems as it runs the function as an `AND` operator.

Comment: You mean the `||`? No, that really is the shortcut-OR operator. I'd start by debugging the height() results, e.g. reading them into variables first so you can examine them in a debugger or alert() them out.

Comment: Its not jquery OR you are looking for, its javascript OR

Comment: @Rup - shortcut? ...what's the long way? :)

Comment: @Nick D'oh, yes, it's usually 'short-circuit'. Sorry.

Comment: Please close the request otherwise mark answer as good. Thx

Answer (score 5):

Your OR operator is right (in fact in your case is simple javascript!)

It seems you have an error here

```
$("#hitbox").animate({ "height" : '0px' },800),
```

fix it as

```
$("#hitbox").animate({ height : '0px' },800);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response! The above code is part of a larger jQuery script, but you're all right, its plain javascript. Thanks for point out the 'height' issue, totally overlooked that one! Thanks again!

Comment: I don't get it. Where's the error (and the fix)? EDIT: Maybe the comma at the end, but I'd be surprised if it made a difference (except perhaps in IE).

Comment: hehe, it's still not doing what i want, but atleast now i know that it's not the OR operator that is bugging it all!

Comment: Looks like the trailing comma has different effect in different browsers. At first I thought you were talking about the quotation marks around `"height"`, which wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Yes sorry I packed the two issues in one line! Nevertheless if code is buggy it shouldn't be in lines you posted

Answer (score 2):

I find sometimes JS operators (in this case your || or) don't compare whole clauses, only the next item starting the clause. you may want to try wrapping your clauses w/ parens like so:

if(($("#sub-wrapper-1").height() < 179) || ($("#sub-wrapper-2").height() < 179 ))